# Inserting into a table, how to insert a auto incrementing ID

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, exception, ado.net

I am trying to insert data into a SQL table but getting an error that I do not have the required number of columns, e.g. I only give it teamname and teamtag, when it also had ID in the SQL table. The ID auto increments though so I am not sure how to make this work, any help is appreciated.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblTeams VALUES(@TEAMNAME, @TEAMTAG)", cs);
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@TEAMNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtTeamName.Text;
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@TEAMTAG", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtTeamTag.Text;

    cs.Open();
    da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cs.Close();
}
```

Error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: Why doesn't your `INSERT` specify the column names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the columns you are populating.

```
INSERT INTO tblTeams (TeamName, TeamTag) VALUES(@TEAMNAME, @TEAMTAG)
```

Comment: I have added this, and it has got past the original error, and I am now faced with another one. "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'T_ID', table 'tSystem.dbo.tblTeams'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

Comment: @user1524116 are you sure T_ID is an IDENTITY column?

Comment: Make sure your column is set up as Identity Specification>(Is Identity)